# pyzabbix unexpected behavior

Tags: python, zabbix

I'm using pyzabbix for the first time.  I'd like to get a history of CPU for a specific host.  I feel I may be using/understanding the library incorrectly since I'm not getting the result I'm expecting.  When I make the following call:

```
time_till = time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
time_from = time_till - 60 * 60 * 4

history = zapi.history.get(hostids=["10632"],
    itemids=["78815"],
    time_from=time_from,
    time_till=time_till,
    output='extend',                                   
    limit=5,
    history=0,
    sortfield='clock', 
    sortorder='DESC'
)
```

I get the following result:

```
[
{
    "clock": "1520260023",
    "itemid": "78783",
    "ns": "353845414",
    "value": "100.0000"
},
{
    "clock": "1520260018",
    "itemid": "78778",
    "ns": "315473640",
    "value": "0.1677"
},
{
    "clock": "1520260018",
    "itemid": "78898",
    "ns": "321212433",
    "value": "40.7421"
},
{
    "clock": "1520260017",
    "itemid": "78777",
    "ns": "313120971",
    "value": "0.3103"
},
{
    "clock": "1520260016",
    "itemid": "78896",
    "ns": "308593447",
    "value": "99.6560"
}
```

]

Based on these results, I have two questions:

1) shouldn't all my results have "itemid": "78815" since this is what I requested in my API call?

2) what is the "ns" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try omitting `hostids` from your request. The `ns` value is the nanosecond value in that second.

Comment: Hi @Richlv - thanks for the reply. Your suggestion certainly works in the fact that it only gives me results for that particular itemid.  Now how do I get results just for a specific host?

Comment: Oh, nevermind.  I get it now.  The itemid is specific to a particular host.